# Bootstrap alert message represented as modal, angular

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap

Bootstrap 3 provides <kbd>[Bootstrap: event messages](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#alerts)</kbd>: `success, info, warning, danger`.

However sometimes the view doesn't have enough space to show up the event message.

Is there easy way to wrap event with <kbd>**[modal](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal)**</kbd> in Angular?

This is a [template](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview) I started to play with

Answer (score 13):

I'll answer on my own question.

### Simple way

The flow is pretty simple and straightforward. We don't reinvent the wheel here.

We don't need nor header neither footer:

**Dialog template HTML:**

```
<div class="modal-body" style="padding:0px">
    <div class="alert alert-{{data.mode}}" style="margin-bottom:0px">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-ng-click="close()" >
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span>
        </button>
        <strong>{{data.boldTextTitle}}</strong> {{data.textAlert}}
    </div>
</div>
```

We even don't need to use `ng-class`:

```
class="alert-{{data.mode}}"
```

where mode might be: `success, info, warning, danger`

---

**Modal Instance Controller:**

```
var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance, data) {
  $scope.data = data;
  $scope.close = function(/*result*/){
    $modalInstance.close($scope.data);
  };
};
```

---

And this is *modal configuration* and *content*:

```
 $scope.data = {
    boldTextTitle: "Done",
    textAlert : "Some content",
    mode : 'info'
  }  

var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
      backdrop: true,
      keyboard: true,
      backdropClick: true,
      size: 'lg',
      resolve: {
        data: function () {
          return $scope.data;
        }
      }
    });
```

Demo <kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/C7e4rj?p=preview)</kbd>

---

[image]

### Directive way

Demo 2 <kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/2vS22f?p=preview)</kbd>

We can put all above written code into directive for better maintenance:

*HTML*

```
<button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="open()" >success
          <my-alert
          bold-text-title="Done"
          text-alert="Some content"
          mode="success"
          ></my-alert>
</button>
```

*Directive*

```
.directive('myAlert', function($modal,$log) {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
          mode: '@',
          boldTextTitle: '@',
          textAlert : '@'
        },
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
        
       scope.data= {
                mode:scope.mode,
                boldTextTitle:scope.boldTextTitle,
                textAlert:scope.textAlert
              }
        
       var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance, data) {
          
           console.log(data);
          
           scope.data= {
              mode:scope.mode || 'info',
              boldTextTitle:scope.boldTextTitle || 'title',
              textAlert:scope.textAlert || 'text'
          }
        };
        
        elm.parent().bind("click", function(e){
           scope.open();
       });
        
     scope.open = function () {
        
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
          templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
          controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
          backdrop: true,
          keyboard: true,
          backdropClick: true,
          size: 'lg',
          resolve: {
            data: function () {
              return scope.data;
            }
          }
        });
    
    
        modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
          scope.selected = selectedItem;
        }, function () {
          $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
        });
    }
  }
  };
})
```

---

Hope it will save time to someone.

Comment: thanks for it. requesting you to add 2 features: 1) option to make it non blocking, with no fading effect 2) auto close after sometime..

Comment: it would be great if you can submit it as a modules on ngmodules.com

Comment: @MaximShoustin Nice alert but how I can open it in JS code just invoking function for example `... myAlert(); ...` ? *In other words show alert without HTML button*

Comment: @AntonDozortsev not at all, the modal lays under directive so you can easily grab modal code and call it without directive

Comment: @MaximShoustin But that is a problem I don't want **copy** mode code all time

Comment: @AntonDozortsev so create somewhere this directive once , add watcher and call some parameter in directive that should trigger watcher and show up the modal

Comment: @MaximShoustin OK. I will try you suggestions. Thanks for all.

Answer (score 1):

I've made a service and controller which depends of eachother:

```
.service('AlertService', function($uibModal){
    /*
        headerText - presents text in header
        bodyText - presents text in body
        buttonText - presents text in button. On its click if method parameters is not passed, modal will be closed.
                    In situation that the method parameters is passed, on its click, method will be called. For situations
                    like that, there is parameter buttonText2 which will be used as cancel modal functionality.
        method - presents passed function which will be called on confirmation
        buttonText2 - presents text in button for cancel

     */
    var alert = function(headerText, bodyText, buttonText, method, buttonText2){

        method = method || function(){};
        buttonText2 = buttonText2 || '';

        $uibModal.open({
            animation: true,
            templateUrl: '/static/angular_templates/alert-modal.html',
            controller: 'AlertModalInstanceCtrl',
            size: 'md',
            resolve: {
                headerText: function () {
                  return headerText;
                },
                bodyText: function () {
                  return bodyText;
                },
                buttonText: function () {
                  return buttonText;
                },
                method: function () {
                    return method;
                },
                buttonText2: function () {
                    return buttonText2;
                }
            }
        });
    };

    return{
        alert: alert
    };

})
.controller('AlertModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $uibModalInstance, headerText, bodyText, buttonText, method, buttonText2) {
    $scope.headerText = headerText;
    $scope.bodyText = bodyText;
    $scope.buttonText = buttonText;
    $scope.method = method;
    $scope.buttonText2 = buttonText2;

    $scope.ok = function () {
        $scope.method();
        $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };

    $scope.cancel = function () {
        $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
});
```

and html file:

```
<!--Modal used for alerts in AlertService-->

<div class="modal-header">
    <h3 class="modal-title">{[{ headerText }]}</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <p>{[{ bodyText }]}</p>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="cancel()" ng-if="buttonText2">{[{ buttonText2 }]}</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">{[{ buttonText }]}</button>
</div>
```

Now, depending for what type you want to use it, you have a few options:
-If you pass headerText, bodyText and buttonText, it will behave like a classic alert modal

```
AlertService.alert('Some header', 'Some message', 'Text button');
```

-If you pass headerText, bodyText, buttonText and method, it will behave like a classic alert modal but with the function which you can pass and later handle in the controller

```
AlertService.alert('Are you sure?', 'Are you sure you want to create this round', 'Ok', $scope.createRound);

$scope.createRound = function(){
//do something
}
```

-And the last one. If you pass all the parameters, it will act like the previous one, just with the possibility to cancel and close modal.

```
AlertService.alert('Are you sure?', 'Are you sure you want to create this round', 'Ok', $scope.createRound, 'Cancel');

$scope.createRound = function(){
//do something
}
```

Of course, if you want to use this, you'll have to inject angular ui bootstrap. **I wasted a lot of time to develop this, but it worth. It was annoying to create every time a new controller, new template and all the other things.**

From the controller then you can easily use it, just inject it first.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answering your own question, it was helpful.

Here's a version as a service you can wire in and fire off from any controller without needing to include directive mark-up.

It uses the latest angular UI Bootstrap paradigm for modals.

It has some convenience methods (info, error, warn, success).

It fires off an event when closed with the data as an event argument in case you need to know that.

Enjoy!

```
angular.module('modal.alert.service', [], function ($provide) {
    'use strict';
    $provide.factory('ModalAlertService', ['$rootScope', '$uibModal', 
                                           function ($rootScope, $uibModal) {

        var factory = {
            alert: function(mode, title, text) {

                var modalData = {
                    mode : mode,
                    title : title,
                    text : text
                };

                var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
                    template: '<div class="modal-body" style="padding:0px">' +
                        '<div class="alert alert-{{data.mode}}" style="margin-bottom:0px">' +
                        '<button type="button" class="close" data-ng-click="close()" >' +
                        '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span>' +
                        '</button><strong>{{data.title}}</strong>: &nbsp; {{data.text}}</div></div>',
                    controller : 'ModalAlertController',
                    backdrop : true,
                    keyboard : true,
                    backdropClick : true,
                    size : 'lg',
                    resolve : {
                        data : function() {
                            return modalData;
                        }
                    }
                });

                modalInstance.result.then(function(data) {
                    $rootScope.$broadcast('modal-alert-closed', { 'data' : data });
                });

            },
            info: function(title, text) {
                factory.alert('info', title, text);
            },
            error: function(title, text) {
                factory.alert('danger', title, text);
            },
            warn: function(title, text) {
                factory.alert('warning', title, text);
            },
            success: function(title, text) {
                factory.alert('success', title, text);
            }
        };

        return factory;

    }]);
}).controller('ModalAlertController', function ($scope, $uibModalInstance, data) {
    $scope.data = data;

    $scope.close = function() {
        $uibModalInstance.close($scope.data);
    };
});
```